# How to set the default option as -h for Python click?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, python-click

#### How to set the default option as -h for Python click?

By default, my script, shows nothing when no arguments is given to the `duh.py`:

```
import click


CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])

@click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.option('--toduhornot', is_flag=True, help='prints "duh..."')
def duh(toduhornot):
    if toduhornot:
        click.echo('duh...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    duh()
```

#### [out]:

```
$ python3 test_click.py -h
Usage: test_click.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --toduhornot  prints "duh..."
  -h, --help    Show this message and exit.



$ python3 test_click.py --toduhornot
duh...


$ python3 test_click.py
```

#### Question:

As shown above, the default prints no information `python3 test_click.py`.

Is there a way such that, the default option is set to `-h` if no arguments is given, e.g.

```
$ python3 test_click.py 
Usage: test_click.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --toduhornot  prints "duh..."
  -h, --help    Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: So if no options are given, then you want to default to help?  You said: *if no arguments is given*, but your example only defines an option, it does not define any arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inherit from `click.Command` and override the `parse_args()` method, you can create a custom class to default to help like:

#### Custom Class

```
import click

class DefaultHelp(click.Command):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_settings = kwargs.setdefault('context_settings', {})
        if 'help_option_names' not in context_settings:
            context_settings['help_option_names'] = ['-h', '--help']
        self.help_flag = context_settings['help_option_names'][0]
        super(DefaultHelp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        if not args:
            args = [self.help_flag]
        return super(DefaultHelp, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to `@click.command()` decorator like:

```
@click.command(cls=DefaultHelp)
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.command()` decorator usually instantiates a
`click.Command` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively
easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we over-ride `click.Command.parse_args()` and check for an empty argument list.  If it is empty then we invoke the help.  In addition this class will default the help to `['-h', '--help']` if it is not otherwise set.

#### Test Code:

```
@click.command(cls=DefaultHelp)
@click.option('--toduhornot', is_flag=True, help='prints "duh..."')
def duh(toduhornot):
    if toduhornot:
        click.echo('duh...')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '--toduhornot',
        '',
        '--help',
        '-h',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            duh(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> --toduhornot
duh...
-----------
> 
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --toduhornot  prints "duh..."
  -h, --help    Show this message and exit.
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --toduhornot  prints "duh..."
  -h, --help    Show this message and exit.
-----------
> -h
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --toduhornot  prints "duh..."
  -h, --help    Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 16):

As of [version 7.1](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/changelog/#version-7-1), one can simply specify `@click.command(no_args_is_help=True)`.

Answer (score 11):

Your structure is not the recommended one, you should use:

```
import click


CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])


@click.group(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command(help='prints "duh..."')
def duh():
    click.echo('duh...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And then `python test_click.py` will print help message:

```
Usage: test_click.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  duh  prints "duh..."
```

So you can use `python test_click.py duh` to call `duh`.

## Update

```
import click


CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])

@click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.option('--toduhornot', is_flag=True, help='prints "duh..."')
def duh(toduhornot):
    if toduhornot:
        click.echo('duh...')
    else:
        with click.Context(duh) as ctx:
            click.echo(ctx.get_help())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    duh()
```

Comment: Hmmm but that imposes a `duh` command and when I do `python test_click.py duh`, it still doesn't print out the help message =(

Comment: Could I also check `if *args == None`?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach I've found

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--option')
@click.pass_context

def run(ctx, option):
    if not option:
        click.echo(ctx.get_help())
        ctx.exit()
```

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I wanted.  Everything else was very convoluted.